# Can I constrain UDP communication to LAN only?

Tags: c#, android, .net, udp, multicast

I have multiple apps setup to work in a **LAN** over Wi-Fi. In order to handshake (establish communication) automatically I'm using `UdpClient` to broadcast the server address. The server is running on **Windows** currently and the apps are developed for **Android** and **iOS**, using the **MAUI** platform.

I've been playing with this setup for a while and I have hooked to the app **lifecycle events** and handshaking is working mostly fine, however last time one of the Androids that I used refused to connect until I turned off the **Mobile data**. I thought that this might happen because the socket is listening for a broadcast on the **WWW** instead of **LAN**, but I don't understand much about networking, so here I am - can I somehow configure `UdpClient` to only use LAN? I thought the `IAddressFamily` constructor might do it, but I can't find sufficient information - it even mentions:

> The UdpClient.UdpClient(AddressFamily) is not suitable for joining a multicast group because it does not perform socket binding.

Comment: Are you sure the problem was _not_ that mobile data connection (i.e. skip the LAN) prevented the device from connecting to the wifi? Outside that, the router should be able to cut off routing udp:yourPortNo to the WAN.

Comment: And for good measure you probably could set a rather small TTL...

Comment: @Fildor I'm not sure of anything, but the wifi was indicating that it was connected. I cannot however reproduce this on any of my 3 phones, so it might have been an incidental thing. From your response I take it that this isn't a "standard" problem? I shouldn't have to specify the network explicitly? 

How would you go about that TTL? I've changed the logic on the server side (broadcast) to stop and restart the broadcast every few seconds, because I sometimes had issues connecting until I restart the server. Do you mean something similar for the client?

Comment: For TTL see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.ttl?view=net-7.0#system-net-sockets-udpclient-ttl